# How do I merge the uncommitted change list with another committed change list?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I am new to perforce and trying to accomplish the following:

I checked out src files of a project and making some changes in the code. Before checking in my changes, I would like to sync my local repo and run some tests locally to make sure that I didn't break anything. How can I merge a file with my changes with the latest version that is already checked-in in the depot? I have two change list number- one is pending change list in my local client and another one is already checked-in in the depot.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which client you're using: P4V? Eclipse? Visual Studio? the p4 command line?

The concept is the same, in all cases: 'p4 sync', then 'p4 resolve'.

In one of the visual clients, it will be 'get latest revision', then 'resolve'.